# ZXing QR Reader Licensing Issues

Tags: ios, licensing, qr-code, zxing

I need to make a QR Reader that has a lotta functionality for the iPhone. I wanted to know whether it is legal for me to take the ScanTest sample code from the ZXingWidget example and then make the modifications I need?

Is there any licensing issue that would stop me from doing that ?? Or will I have to start afresh ? This is for an in-company project

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check out the faq at `http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/LicenseQuestions`

Coming from a non-lawyer quoting non-lawyers, you can.

> What Do I Have To Do To Comply?
>   We aren't lawyers, so can't claim to
>   give legal advice. We can reproduce the requirements in the license's
>   "Redistribution" section here for you:
>
> You must give any other recipients of the Work or Derivative Works a
>   copy of this License; and You must cause any modified files to carry
>   prominent notices stating that You changed the files; and You must
>   retain, in the Source form of any Derivative Works that You
>   distribute, all copyright, patent, trademark, and attribution notices
>   from the Source form of the Work, excluding those notices that do not
>   pertain to any part of the Derivative Works; and If the Work includes
>   a "NOTICE" text file as part of its distribution, then any Derivative
>   Works that You distribute must include a readable copy of the
>   attribution notices contained within such NOTICE file, excluding those
>   notices that do not pertain to any part of the Derivative Works, in at
>   least one of the following places: within a NOTICE text file
>   distributed as part of the Derivative Works; within the Source form or
>   documentation, if provided along with the Derivative Works; or, within
>   a display generated by the Derivative Works, if and wherever such
>   third-party notices normally appear. The contents of the NOTICE file
>   are for informational purposes only and do not modify the License. You
>   may add Your own attribution notices within Derivative Works that You
>   distribute, alongside or as an addendum to the NOTICE text from the
>   Work, provided that such additional attribution notices cannot be
>   construed as modifying the License. A common way to comply, in a
>   product that is delivered only in binary form and not source form
>   (e.g. an application download) is to add a mention of the project, and
>   link to its license (in our view, a link to the project website is
>   ultimately also fine), in a "Help" or "About" screen of the
>   application.
>
> Can This Be Used In Commercial Products?
>   The license does not forbid
>   this. The license terms still apply, of course.
>
> Please see below our thoughts on the spirit of the open-source
>   license. If you are selling a product based on something that is free,
>   it should add to and innovate on this project. Otherwise it is more a
>   copy than anything.